# Meissner effect and levitation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity, classical-electrodynamics

In a field less than critical field, decreasing the temperature below the critical temperature will eliminate the magnetic field inside a superconductor and increase the magnetic field around it. (Meissner effect). But does it related to levitation effect of magnet on a superconductor? What makes it float in air?

Comment: In a textbook the effect is explained this way: "The diamagnetic nature of a superconductor has some interesting mechanical consequences. For a diamagnetic material the magnetization is in the opposite sense, and a diamagnetic material is repelled by a permanent magnet." (University physics).

I wonder why it mentions diamagnetism? A diamagnetic material is slightly repelled by magnet but the mechanism is different from the effect of the Faraday's law of induction. Is the levitation due to diamagnetism?

Comment: I have another question as the induced current creates an internal magnetic field that exactly cancels the external field. If the superconductor behave like this it is actually a very strong electromagnet and it also has its north and south pole. Why it can be levitated so stably while a permanent magnet cannot?